# Abstracting if statement and return by a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function like this:

```
def test():
    x = "3" # In actual code, this is computed

    if x is None:
        return None

    y = "3"

    if y is None:
        return None

    z = "hello"

    if z is None:
        return None
```

Is there a way of making the `if` statement go away and abstract it with some function. I'm expecting something like this:

```
def test():
    x = "3"
    check_None(x)

    y = "3"
    check_None(y)

    z = "hello"
    check_None(z)
```

Ideally, `check_None` should alter the control flow if the parameter passed to it is None. Is this possible?

Note: Working on Python 2.7.

Comment: Only if `check_None` raises an exception that `test` doesn't catch - it can't force `test` to `return None`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, I think I get the idea. Yes `test` doesn't catch it.

Comment: Does `z` depend on `y`, and `y` depend on `x`?  BTW, I know this is only semantics, but `if` is not a loop, and you can write on one line if that makes you happier.

Comment: @cdarke Yes, they depend. On some cases, they don't. But I want to just avoid the if checks and abstract it over a function.

Comment: OK, so how is `None` generated in the calculations?  Is it returned by some other function in a module?

Comment: @cdarke Yes, None is returned by some other function.

Comment: Not counting side effects from calculating x, y and z - your function can be replaced by "def test(): pass". What do you want to return from your test function if all of them are not None?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily code it in some thing like this.

```
def test():
    #compute x, y, z
    if None in [x, y, z]:
       return None
    # proceed with rest of code
```

An even better way would be to use an generator to generate value x, y, z so that you only does computation for one value at a time.

```
def compute_values():
    yield compute_x()
    yield compute_y()
    yield compute_z()

def test():
    for value in compute_values():
        if value is None:
           return None
```

Comment: Which means you have to do the calculation **first**. You'd not get to exit early if `x` or `y` resolved to `None`.

Comment: That is why I recommended use of generator

Comment: Instead of your `for` loop you could just do `if None in (x,y,z): return None`

Comment: Ok, thats even better, but in generator solution i guess I have to use a loop

Comment: Please mark it correct if you find my solution helpful

Comment: That's fine taking my suggestion, but you have used a list instead of a tuple, why?

Comment: Actually I am more concerned about the solution with generator, and yeah using tuple might be little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if we should do it like this, but one of the hacks could be like this, Also create your own exception class and only catch that particular exception so that no other exceptions are accidentally caught by the except and return None.

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def check_none(x):
    if x is None:
        raise MyException

def test():
    try:
        z=None
        check_none(z)
    except MyException, e:
        return None

return_value = test()
```

Comment: Don't use exceptions for flow control - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259660/example-of-using-exceptions-to-control-flow

Comment: @julka I'm actually ok with exceptions to achieve what I want. But in this solution I want `check_none` to return None and don't want `try-except` blocks.

Comment: @Sibi:  this is really what exception handling is for.

Comment: @Sibi You do not want try, except outside of the function, is that right? Inside the function would be ok?